# What is a non-trivial counterexample to my generalization to continuity of integral equations?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Classical theorem states: $f(x) = \int_0^x g(t) dt $ is continuous. But suppose my well defined integrand also depends on $x$, i.e.,

$$f(x) = \int_0^x g(x,t)\, dt $$

This wouldn't work, and a trivial counter-example would be to let $g(x,t)=p(x)q(t)$ and let $p(x)$ be a step function. But what is a counterexample if $g(x,t)$ cannot be factored into separable functions?

Comment: If $\lambda(x)$ does not depends on $t$ then you can just factor it outside the integral.

Comment: @Lelouch good point, I'll edit my question

Comment: Then you can try to make the integral on an interval independent of x (like doing a change of variable) and use some parameter-depend integral theorem. Also note that $\lambda$ is no longer defined after your edit.

Comment: @Lelouch my integral in reality is pretty complicated (from an open problem). Is there always techniques to do this? I would really hope the statement in my question work in general : (

Comment: Do you have any hypothesis on $g$ ? You will at least need the continuity of $g$ for the $x$ variable.

Comment: @Lelouch I can assume that $g(x,t)$ is continuous in $t$, and its integrable.

Comment: What about $g(x,t)=1/(x+t)^2$? Its going to be very hard to get a positive result in general. Perhaps if its a convolution or you have an integral kernel  you can begin to have hope.

Comment: Probably not quite what you are looking for but could you not just take $g(x,t) = p_1(x)q_1(t) + p_2(x) q_2(t)$ with $p_1,p_2$ discontinuous, $p_1\neq p_2$, $q_1\neq q_2$. Then I don't think you could write $g(x,t) = p(x) q(t)$ for some $p,q$.

Comment: Then if you don't want even finite sums of separable functions you could take something like $g(x,t) = \sum_{j=1}^\infty p_j(x) q_j(t)$ which (hopefully) wouldn't converge to a separable function.

Comment: Or how about $g(x,t) = \sin (H(x-1)+t)$ where $H$ is the Heaviside function?

Comment: @CalvinKhor This is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!